# Setting up development environment in micro-services architecture

Tags: microservices, gateway

We are moving towards developing a web app in a micro-services architecture.
We thought about running the services behind a API gateway that will handle authentication and will proxy the requests to the appropriate services.
We have encountered a problem while setting up the development environment. How can we develop a service in a local machine (laptop) and test and run it in a way that is similar to the production (behind the gateway)?

Consider the following requirements:

- Inter process communication (B2B)
- Manage and sync different versions
- Access the service with authentication token (produced by the gateway)

Comment: I'm interested in this, but would it be better on programmers.stackexchange or similar?

Comment: @Candroid - Which framework you are using for your application? Is it a nodejs base web-app?

Comment: We are aiming to use a variety of frameworks from different languages, each with its own pros for the service

Comment: Also asked here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/332972/setting-up-development-environment-in-micro-services-architecture

Answer (score 0):

Difficulty to setup development environment for microservices is proportional to the number of microservices. I have a running setup on my laptop with 2 microservices along with eureka, zuul gateway with oAuth2, an authorization server and spring cloud config. Beyond this I have not tried as it will start becoming unmanageable.

In this case it is better to have the development environment on cloud. You can choose any cloud provider and avail a free subscription for sometime. For eg. Amazon gives you 750 hours of linux time free for a month. You can create any number of instances as you need(with minimal cost after free usage).